# CNTK - incomplete training of model

Tags: python, cntk

Using the CNTK python API I have trained a three layer feed forward network to play a simple grid based board game.   If I use a small board (6 x 6) grid, the model trains successfully.   The model plays the game with 100% success over 100 games.   However, if I increase the board size to 21 x 21 the training appears to saturate at about 90% success over 100 games.

Increasing the training time or changing the training parameters does not appear to improve the performance of the model.

- am I missing something?
- does CNTK support the use of "dropouts"?
- are there other techniques to improve the training

Answer (score 0):

Yes dropout is supported. Currently documentation located here:

https://cntk.ai/pythondocs/cntk.ops.html?highlight=dropout#cntk.ops.dropout

What kind of activation functions are you using? If you are using Sigmoids, try ReLUs. If using ReLU's it is possible that they are dying during training due to large gradients flowing. Try using Leaky ReLU or Param ReLU. All these are supported by the toolkit.